# How to populating one column in a dataframe from the truncated value of another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, truncate

I have column in a `Pandas` dataframe (final_combine_df) that is called `GEOID`. I will have a 15 character string number like this : '371899201001045'. I want to create a new column in my data frame called `'CB_GrpID'` that is equal to just the first 12 characters of the `GEOID` values (ex: '371899201001'). I tried this, but it just returned the same `GEOID` value (non-truncated) in the new `'CB_GrpID'`:

```
final_combine_df['CB_GrpID'] = final_combine_df['GEOID'][:12]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
final_combine_df.iloc[0]['CB_GrpID']
>>371899201001045
```

Comment: `final_combined_df['GEOID'].str[:12]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [`pandas.Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html)

[Working with text](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html)
The `str` accessor is what you're looking for.  It gives access to the strings in each cell along with "vectorized" string methods.

```
final_combined_df['GEOID'].str[:12]
```

What you were doing:

```
final_combined_df['GEOID'][:12]
```

Was just getting the first 12 elements of the column.

Comment: Yep, that did it!

Answer (score 0):

Follow this format. Use a lambda function to return the first 12 digits of a string. Note python starts at index 0 and the upper limit is exclusive not inclusive, meaning the last element you want is at index 11, however you set the upper limit to 12 to ensure that 11 is included. Just FYI in case you were unaware.

`df[‘new_var’] = df[‘old_var’].apply(lambda x: x[:12])`

Comment: Using `apply` with a `lambda` is **not** recommended in this situation.

Comment: @piRSquared why is that? .apply() has always done me well when I need to create a column based on data/conditions from another column in a data frame.

Comment: Because `apply` is a last resort when none of the existing api get your task done.  If nothing else works, you can `apply` a function to every element in a loop.  The whole purpose of the "other" api is give advantages over a `for` loop.  In this case, you have api specifically developed to handle columns of strings.  `apply` is slower, `lambda` is less readable, and the combination is less elegant.